# how to access mobile settings from cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I'm developing mobile application from cordova and i designed the app to work in offline mode 
I'm trying to access mobile settings if the user checked automatic date and time using Cordova

Comment: When you say "mobile settings", do you mean the mobile data settings page (to enable/disable mobile data)?

Comment: I mean date and time settings(Update time automatically service) in Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's not an existing Cordova plugin that provides the ability to show the date/time settings page on Android. Having said that, it'd be pretty easy to create your own. Off the top of my head, you can put together your own "Date Setting" plugin something like this:

**plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="cordova-plugin-date-setting"
    version="0.0.1">

    <name>Date Setting</name>
    <description></description>
    <author></author>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>ecosystem:cordova</keywords>
    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
    </engines>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="DateSetting" >
                <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugins.DateSetting"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <js-module src="datesetting.js" name="Diagnostic">
            <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.DateSetting" />
        </js-module>
        <source-file src="DateSetting.java" target-dir="src/cordova/plugins" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

**datesetting.js**

```
var DateSetting = (function(){

    DateSetting = {
        open: function(successFn, errorFn){
            cordova.exec(successFn,errorFn,'DateSetting','open',[]);
        }
    };
    return DateSetting;
});
module.exports = new DateSetting();
```

**DateSetting.java**

```
package cordova.plugins;

import android.content.Intent;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class DateSetting extends CordovaPlugin {
    public DateSetting() {}

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        try {
            if (action.equals("open")){
                cordova.getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
                callbackContext.success();
            }else {
                callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
                return false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e ) {
            callbackContext.error("Exception occurred: ".concat(e.getMessage()));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```